# Reproducing a certain status of the repo in git in a clean way

Tags: git, clearcase

In clearcase, in order to reproduce a status, I  create a config spec file and put a label on it. Later can use the config spec with a certain label to reproduce a certain status of my project.

In git, for now, I tag on commits and do a few cherry pics to get back to a certain status.

Is there a cleaner way to achieve the same in git?

Comment: If you have a tagged commit, all you should have to do is checkout that commit/tag and you should get back to the state from that commit. For what reason do you need to do the cherry-picks?

Comment: 2 reasons: First because I have many contributors to the project and and I would like to get to older versions of files also from them. and second because I need verification set up also, mostly never merged with development files. I still manage with checkout out and cherry picking, but never clean easy to share as with config spec and labels in clearcase.

Answer (score 0):

No need for cherry-picking or special "config spec": you can at any time checkout a new branch from an old commit:

```
git checkout -b aTmpBranch <oldCommit>
```

> I have many contributors to the project and and I would like to get to older versions of files also from them.

Then yes, if you don't merge their all branch but only some of their commits, cherry-picking would be needed.